# How to link each collection by reference in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have 3 collections i.e. technicians, services and tags. Every technicians having services and every services having some tags. My question is how to link multiple collection to each other and get result like this -
"select technicians.name, services.name, tags.name from technicians join on technicians.services = services.id join tags on tags.id = services.tagid"

```
technician collection

{   "_id": {     "$oid": "63fdbae1d252217c62366899"   },   "name": "John",   "services": {     "$oid": "63fdba76d252217c62366893"   } }

services collection

{   "_id": {     "$oid": "63fdba32d252217c62366892"   },   "name": "plumber",   "tagid": {     "$oid": "63fdbadbd252217c62366897"   } }

tags collection

{   "_id": {     "$oid": "63fdbabed252217c62366896"   },   "name": "motor", "_id": {     "$oid": "63fdbabed2522dfc62366896"   },   "name": "wiring" }
```

But this issue is this fetching all tags, it should return only tags which is link to category and technician collections. Thank you.

I tried this

`db.technicians.aggregate( [ { $lookup:   {     from: "services",     localField: "services",     foreignField: "_id",     as: "myservices",   },  $lookup: {   from: "tags",      localField: "tagid",   foreignField: "tags._id",   as: "mytags", }  } ] )`

Comment: "This giving result like this Result is"{
   "_id":"ObjectId(""63fdbae1d252217c62366899"")",
   "name":"john",
   "services":"ObjectId(""63fdba76d252217c62366893"")",
   "mytags":[
      {
         "_id":"ObjectId(""63fdbabed252217c62366896"")",
         "name":"motor"
      },
      {
         "_id":"ObjectId(""63fdbadbd252217c62366897"")",
         "name":"geyser"
      }
   ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tag` should linked to `services`

```
db.technicians.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "services",
      localField: "services",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "myservices",
      
    },
    
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$myservices"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "tags",
      localField: "myservices.tagid",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "myservices.mytags",
      
    },
    
  },
  
])
```

[MONGO PLAYGROUND](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nL8uI475taC)